# Send string via bluetooth

Tags: android

I am using this code to send a string to other android paired device. Output  is the string i need to send an it is declared public but this code not working. Please help me to correct this code

```
try{
    BluetoothDevice[] devices = (BluetoothDevice[]) bondedDevices.toArray();
    BluetoothDevice device = devices[0];
    ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();

    BluetoothSocket socket= device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
    socket.connect();
    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(output.getBytes());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Sent...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
catch(Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

Comment: Can we see the logcat output? Add e.printStackTrace(); to the catch block.

Comment: Could an outputStream.flush() help?

Comment: no exception generated on try